# python neural nets explanation

Tags: python, dataframe, neural-network

```
model = Sequential()

nFeatures = X.shape[1]
model.add(Dense(20,
        input_dim=nFeatures,
        activation="relu",
        kernel_initializer="random_normal",
        bias_initializer="zeros"))

nOutput = y.shape[1]
model.add(Dense(nOutput,
        activation="softmax",
        kernel_initializer="random_normal",
        bias_initializer="zeros"))

model.compile(optimizer="adam",
        loss="categorical_crossentropy",
        metrics=["categorical_accuracy"])

model.summary()
```

Can somebody please explain to me the meaning of these three big parts?
I understand that the first one is the inner layer, the second the output layer and the third part is some kind of compiler.
But I have problems understanding the single parts.
Why do we use the Strings relu, random_normal, softmax, adam,....? What is the meaning behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, in this line:

```py
model = Sequential()
```

You are using a wrapper class to build a sequential model, a model where every layer output is connected to the input of the next layer.
Your model is composed of two layers, the first layer:

- Takes an input of dimension `nFeatures`.
- Is using a `relu` function as activation. The REctifier Linear Unit is a function which looks something like this:
  [Relu graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4Q3f.png)
  As for every activation function it is applied to the inner matricial product of the layer: `layers_weights @ input + bias`
- You can specify how to initialize the weights of the Dense layer, this is done with the `kernel_initializer` argument, here the `random_normal` means that every weights will have a normal distribution.
- the `bias_initializer` is the same idea for the bias term (the term added to the iner matrix multiplication)

Your second layer uses another activation function, e.g. `softmax` which is useful when you want to predict probability distributions, e.g. for classification tasks.\

The third chunk of code is where you compile your model, to compile it you must specify two arguments `loss` and `optimizer`:

- The `loss` is the function which takes the predictions of your model and the ground truth values, and evaluate the goodness of the predictions. There is a number of them and every loss function has its specificity. You could even define one by yourself. Every loss have one common characteristic, less is better. Here you use the `categorical_crossentropy` function which is a good loss function to do multi-class classification (I'm assuming that's what you are up to).
- The `optimizer` argument takes the loss function output. And computes the gradient for every weight/parameter of your model. There is a number of different optimizer, the `adam` optimizer is a combination of `AdaGrad` and `rmsprop` optimizers. Don't worry if those don't mean anything to you. You will find a gentle introduction to the adam optimizer here. [Gentle Introduction to the Adam Optimization Algorithm for Deep Learning](https://machinelearningmastery.com/adam-optimization-algorithm-for-deep-learning/)

Answer (score 0):

```
model = Sequential()
```

We are using the Keras Sequential API to build models. There is the alternative functional API. Sequential API allows to create models layer-by-layer for most problems. It does not allow you to create models that share layers or have multiple inputs or outputs.

```
nFeatures = X.shape[1]
```

We get the number of features. X.shape = (No_of_inputs, no_of_features)

Number of inputs will be equal to the number of units/neurons in the input layer.

```
model.add(Dense(20,
        input_dim=nFeatures,
        activation="relu",
        kernel_initializer="random_normal",
        bias_initializer="zeros"))
```

We define the first input layer with nFeatures units along with another dense layer with 20 units.
Dense layers have a linear part and a non-linear part. The linear part is the eqn of a line Wx+b where W is the weights matrix and b is the bias vector.
The non-linear part would be an activation function which is just a non-linear function which adds that randomness to the weights and these also affect the model convergence speed or the training time to convergence, the loss etc. Using ReLU Rectified Liner Unit function here.
Bias & Kernal initializers defines how the bias and kernal/weight matrix should be initialized. Certain heuristic and research evident methods such as Xavier initializer, Glorot normal initializer, random_normal are used to initialize the weight matrix as these help in preventing exploding and vanishing gradients. Bias vector just has to be zeros.

```
nOutput = y.shape[1]
model.add(Dense(nOutput,
        activation="softmax",
        kernel_initializer="random_normal",
        bias_initializer="zeros"))
```

Define the first input layer with nOutput units. Number of units/neurons in the output layer will depend on the number of classes.
Ex: Binary classifier 1 output. Classes 0 or 1. Here this is a multi-class classifier. So number of units/neurons in the output layer = number of classes.

```
model.compile(optimizer="adam",
        loss="categorical_crossentropy",
        metrics=["categorical_accuracy"])
```

We define the optimizer which is the optimization algorithm used to minimize the loss function to converge the network during training. Adam stands for Adaptive Momentum. Gradient descent, Nadam, SGD etc can be used here. This is the algorithm which defines the way in which the gradients are computed to minimize the loss function and these gradients are computed in a chain fashion starting from the output unit back to the layer 1 and the weights and bias matrices are adjusted accordingly.
Finally, Loss function is the metric used to evaluate the network at each iteration and to determine how the weights should be adjusted in the iterative training process. The 'metric' argument is usually used to monitor other loss functions/metric. For a classifier here, it can be precision, recall, accuracy etc. We already see the categorical_crossentropy values during training as 'loss' so it won't be passed as a metric.

Now the model.fit function can be called passing the train data (or both train and validation data), epoch count, batch_size etc to start the training.

Hope that helps! Thanks!